# Propagate the header to all the services of a request

Tags: spring-boot, http-headers, spring-cloud-gateway

My question is about headers with Spring Router. I have an application that uses multiple application layers. The first layer is the REST service, the 2nd layer is a soa service (name it S1) which receives the request from the REST service. The S1 service does some processing and calls several soa services in sequence.

User --> Gateway --> REST  --> Gateway --> S1 -- > Gateway --> S2
-- > Gateway --> S3

My problem is that the user can send a custom header to the Gateway and then the Gateway forward it to the REST service. That's ok.  But when the REST service want to reach the S1 service,  it call the Gateway but it does not contains the custom header just added from the user.  I want this header to be spread over all servives.

My goal is that I want my Gateway to check if the custom header is present and forward the request to a different instance of the requested service. In the above case, it is possible that I have a version 1 and 2 of my S1 service. I would like to be able to tell my Gateway that if the custom header is present, it must redirect the request to version 2 while the other requests will go to version 1. My goal is not to modify the code of the different services because I don't have access to all of them.

If there is a solution for that, i will be able to deploy a new instance of S3.  Ask the QA to do some tests while the client reach the previous version. When the QA has finished its tests, i can change the Gateway to forward all the client to the new instance of S3.

I Hope it is clear.  Maybe the solution is right in front of my eyes but I can't see it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using resttemplate for calling the services? Will this custom header have the same name?

Comment: I did not know resttemplate.  I'm going to read about it.  For the custom header, yes our idea is to have the same name for all the request flow.  ex: testRequest=true.  This header need to be propagate from the REST service to the S3.

Comment: Only to check if I you give you a useful answer, you are using Eureka Zull in your gateway and the microservices are eureka client, right?

Comment: No.  would that be the component that i miss?

Comment: In my microservices projects, in general I use an Eureka Server (DiscoveryServer), and all microservices has EurekaClient, they "subscribe" into eureka server, so I add a gateway project with "Netflix Zull", it will subscribe into eureka server as well (because its a eureka client), this one will map all endpoints of microservices, then, the requests will be send only to gateway microservice that will call the correct endpoint

Comment: Does this ensure that headers can be passed from one service to another? because for now my problem is that every call to my gateway is like a new call without previous header